# How does cat handle bitmaps?

Tags: cat

Curiosity here. I cat-ed a bitmap and expected it to display one ascii character for each byte in the file. The first few characters were thus as expected (BM6), but I noticed further down that it also displayed non-ascii characters in the terminal like "ڮ", "Ѿ", "ӷ", etc.

Why is this? What is cat doing here?

(The bitmap I used has bitsPerPixel=8, so it can't be a representation of a multi-byte pixel, right?)

Comment: cat's doing nothing except sending characters to the terminal, which is doing what terminals do: display characters.

Comment: You probably have a UTF-8 capable terminal emulator. This means it will display many non asciii characters assuming that it has the font information to do so. So if the first byte in the file is 0x42 it will display "B", and if later there is 0xd1 followed by  0xbe then you will get "Ѿ"

Comment: I see. I'm used to thinking of encoding as a property of the file, but I guess that doesn't make sense with a bitmap. So now I'm trying to get my Mac terminal to cat the bitmap with just ascii representation. (Proving tricky!)

Comment: To those interested -- I found that `cat file.bmp | hexdump -C` is a nice way of displaying the bytes in the bmp as ascii

Comment: `hexdump -C  file.bmp` will do the same thing with no pipe and just one program running. Also `od -c file.bmp`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It writes them to standard output.

What happens next is up to whatever standard output is.  If it is a terminal device, then the behaviour is determined by the terminal, and *is nothing to do with `cat`*.

When it comes to the behaviour of the terminal, several things are important:

- ASCII is a 7-bit character encoding.  An 8-bit byte can represent twice as many things as in the ASCII character set.  What the other 128 values mean has been the subject of a *lot* of back and forth in the 1970s, 1980s, and 1990s.  We had single-byte encodings, double-byte encodings, code pages, ISO 8859, and the parts of ASCII itself that were intended to be variant (or that changed in later editions of the standard).  And that is not even to get into the complexities of ISO 2022/ECMA-35 and switchable character sets.

  There's a myth that there's a "plain ASCII" world out there.  This has not really been true for almost half a century.  You will almost never be in a situation nowadays where you are looking at solely actual ASCII.
- Nowadays, a terminal *emulator* is, more likely than not, using UTF-8, a variable-length encoding of Unicode where each code point is one or more bytes.  It was starting to become commonplace 15 years ago.
- *Even were* you working with just ASCII, some characters are *printing* characters, that a terminal will render with a printable graphic, and the others are *control* characters, which have various non-printing effects (including, in the case of ␀, no effect at all).  Unicode is more complex, but the basic idea that only some code points are actually displayable is still roughly true.
- Terminals decode their received byte streams into characters according to what character encoding *they are currently set to use*.  This varies quite significantly from terminal to terminal.  Terminal *emulators* usually have some menu option where this decoding can be changed on the fly by the user, at whim.

On the gripping hand, looking at a bitmap by printing it to a terminal with `cat` is madness.  Learn the joy of `hexdump`, [or `od`](https://superuser.com/a/706129/38062).  [No `cat` should be involved at all](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat).